# using json strings instead of children subtrees

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database structure like:

```
base
  child1
     sub tree of ~10 children and ~5 levels deep
  child2
     sub tree of ~10 children and ~5 levels deep
  ...
```

now I *always only* get/set whole children, that is I will never need a ref pointing inside the children's sub tree directly.

my question is, in this case, will it be more efficient in terms of speed and/or space to store each subtree as a JSON string and convert to/from on the client ?

thanks

Comment: I doubt anyone would have a direct answer for this, but you can test it easily by wiring up a few different nodes and testing load times.

Comment: I was hoping someone with knowledge of firebase internals would ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stored JSON strings in Firebase databases on several occasions:

- to store GeoJSON features; and
- to store each user's application settings.

The GeoJSON was stored as a string primarily because of that format's extensive use of arrays for coordinates. And the application settings had a significant amount of nesting.

In both situations, the data was opaque as far as Firebase was concerned and there was no need for its content to be queried.

I have no knowledge of Firebase's internals, but I very much doubt you will see any efficiency or performance benefits from storing JSON strings. In fact, efficiency (and possibly performance) will likely be worse. You can be close to certain that Firebase does not store its internal data as JSON. That means that in storing data as JSON strings, you are likely to be storing *more* data, as the JSON will contain the keys in addition to the values. And that data will also include braces, quotes and escapes, etc.

If the data is larger, more information will need to be transferred across the network and that cannot help performance.

You might want to do some profiling yourself. Just create database full of unencoded data and another full of JSON strings and compare the size difference. The 'Usage' tab in the console will give you an indication of overall database size. And if you are interested in what's actually transferred, use the Chrome Dev Tools (or similar) to have a look at the web socket traffic on the 'Network' tab.

In short, if efficiency and performance are your only reasons for considering storing JSON strings, you probably won't want to do it.